# CSS - set interval for font-size

Tags: css, font-size

I need to be able to set a range for a font-size.
I would need the range to go from 7px to 14px.
But I can't do it, can you help me?
I tried like this:

```
calc(7px + (100vw - 90rem)/100)
```

Comment: try `clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()

Comment: @SimoneNigro Thk so much